# Is the value of this resistor critical and if so why?

Tags: circuit-analysis

The following is a circuit used for the endstops of a 3D printer. [The full schematic](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-V1.3/blob/master/BTT%20SKR%20V1.4/Hardware/BTT%20SKR%20V1.4-SCH.pdf)

I understand that when the switch is closed (pressed) the signal Z- goes low. R16 is used as a pull-up resistor so that the circuit is not in an indeterminate state when the switch is open.

My question is about R17.  What is its role and is its value critical? Would it make a difference if R17 was 100 ohm?

On my board the value of R4 and R13 are both 1k but R17 is 100 ohms and it is the Z- signal that seems to misbehave.

[image: Endstop circuit]

[image: Endstop switch circuit]

Comment: What is it feeding into?

Comment: It's not connected to anything therefore its value is hyper-non-critical.

Comment: Its going to the input pin of a microcontroller [link](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-V1.3/blob/master/BTT%20SKR%20V1.4/Hardware/BTT%20SKR%20V1.4-SCH.pdf)

Comment: What does misbehave mean? What should it do? How does it differ from the behaviour of the X and Y stop switches?

Comment: So the limit switches should trigger when the print head reaches the end of each axis. X and Y trigger correctly and always in the same place but the Z switch seams to trigger at a slightly different place each time (inconsistent).

Comment: What is the schematic of your end stop switch/LED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the pull-ups are pulling to 3.3 V, the same as the MCU power supply in your linked schematic. Meanwhile the sensors are powered from +5V so their output will be feeding 5 V into a 3.3 V input. It looks like the series resistors on the input are a hack to limit the input current to (5 - 3.3 - 0.6)/1k = 1.1 mA to each input and out to the 3.3 V supply via the chip's input protection diode (which is where the 0.6 V comes in).

This wouldn't be considered high-class design but it probably works. It relies on the chip being able to absorb all the input currents via its supply pin as it probably can't be absorbed back into the PSU. With only three inputs giving up to 3.3 mA it should be OK as the CPU will consume more than that. (Otherwise the 3.3 V rail would rise up towards 5 V.)

> My question is about R17. What is its role and is its value critical? Would it make a difference if R17 was 100 ohm?

Yes. 100 Ω would give ten times the input current and I would think that it may overload the input, possibly burn out the protection diode and then the chip is in trouble.

> On my board the value of R4 and R13 are both 1k but R17 is 100 ohms and it is the Z- signal that seems to misbehave.

Add 1k in series with the input and see if that helps. It may be too late though. If you think the chip is still working you could make a potential divider on the input with 1k8 and 3k3 resistor to drop the input voltage to less than 3.3 V max.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjgzgZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Voltage divider for the Z-limit input.*

Comment: Plenty of chips today are designed to tolerate inputs greater than Vdd for exactly the reasons found here.. The integrated input protection diode to Vdd needs to be removed and some other protection used though.

Comment: How would you remove an input protection diode integrated into a microcontroller?

Comment: It would depends on the chip fabrication method. Yes, I know they're typically parasitic but a way must have been found !

Comment: Well the user can't remove them other than by burning them out!

Comment: So, why don't these burn out ?  https://www.onsemi.com/products/standard-logic/logic-gates/74lcx00

Comment: See [page 7](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/74LCX00-D.pdf) of the datasheet. There is no overvoltage input protection diode. (There is one to protect the input if it goes negative.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113968/discussion-between-graham-stevenson-and-transistor).